# Export Gridview to excel with Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, gridview

in my web page , i have a gridview with data and some images, Here i want to export gridview to excel with Images,I'm trying with below code, it export data only, here how can i export to excel with images ?

```
 Response.ClearContent();
    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}", "Customers.xls"));
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.HeaderRow.Style.Add("background-color", "Red");
    for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Columns.Count - 2; i++)
    {
        GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Style.Add("background-color", "Red");
    }
    GridView1.RenderControl(htw);
    Response.Write(sw.ToString());
    Response.End();
```

here i am using Openoffice calc to read excel files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace function code with this

```
private void Excel_Export()
    {
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",
 "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
Response.Charset = "";

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataBind();

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];

    //Apply text style to each Row
    row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
}

GridView1.RenderControl(hw);

//style to format numbers to string
string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
Response.Write(style);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
}
```

Refer this [link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-with-Images-to-Word-Excel-and-PDF-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx) for more details

Comment: Hello mehul-bhalala. I am tried above code,but i dint get images while exporting..

Comment: you have to refer given link

Comment: how can i export Ajax Control Toolkit line chart to excel can any one tell me how to do this.

Comment: Ranjeet Kumar please refer below link  http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-ASPNet-Chart-Control-to-Excel-File-with-Caption-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: I tried this also but it not working i am using framework 3.5. if any other way to do this can you suggest me how to do this.